# to_numeric(..., downcast='float') is too aggressive

Tags: python, pandas

Illustration for floats: Behavior is unexpected and potentially harmful.

For big floats, using to_numeric with downcast='float' appears to be just as forceful as using .astype('float32'), in that it returns a downcasted result even if that result is no longer == the argument.

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)

s = pd.Series(9876543210.0)
s.astype('float32')  # 9876543488.00; dtype: float32
s.astype('float32') == s  # False
pd.to_numeric(s, downcast='float')  # 9876543488.00; dtype: float32
pd.to_numeric(s, downcast='float') == s  # False
```

Expected output:

```
s = pd.Series(9876543210.0)
pd.to_numeric(s, downcast='float')  # 9876543210.00; dtype: float64
pd.to_numeric(s, downcast='float') == s  # True
```

please give me any solution if anybody know.

Comment: What solution? You are casting to float32 (since `downcast='float'` picks the smallest available float dtype). There is no float32 that is equal to 9876543210. You can't both downcast to float32 and keep the precision of float64. You know that old joke "doctor, it hurts me when I do this" - "then don't do that"? :)

Comment: so what should i do for compress my large pandas data frame?

Comment: That's your decision. A column can only contain one numpy type. You either downcast it, and lose precision, or you don't, and lose memory. You can't have everything. If your frame is too big, see if you can process it in chunks. I can't tell you, as I don't know what you want to do. All I'm saying is that what you are requesting is not possible.